# An Issue when retrieving Identity column ADO.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, ado, sqldataadapter

I have an issue on my code when multi users work on the same time. that it shows me an error:

'Column 'id' is constrained to be unique.  Value '9' is already present.'

I tried to simulate it on a small code so you can understand the problem.

let's assume we have a database with one table named Table1

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
[id] int not null IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
[Name] nvarchar(max) not null,
);
```

and I have this simple console app :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string connectionString = "Server=.;Database=Test;User Id=sa;Password=;";
        using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        connection.Open();

        using var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from [Table1]", connection)
        {
            InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("Insert into Table1 ([Name]) values(@NameParam); Select [ID],[Name] from [Table1] where [id]= SCOPE_IDENTITY();",connection)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.Text
            }
        };
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NameParam", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40, "Name"));
        adapter.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.Both;

        // MissingSchemaAction adds any missing schema to 
        // the DataTable, including identity columns
        adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;

        adapter.RowUpdated += Adapter_RowUpdated;


        var table = new DataTable();

        adapter.Fill(table);


        // this insert command simulates another user on the network inserted a row 
        var anotherInsertCommand = new SqlCommand("Insert into Table1 ([Name]) values('Test1');",connection);
        anotherInsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


        DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
        newRow["Name"] = "test2";
        table.Rows.Add(newRow);

        DataRow newRow1 = table.NewRow();
        newRow1["Name"] = "test3";
        table.Rows.Add(newRow1);

        DataTable changedData = table.GetChanges();

        adapter.Update(changedData);

        table.Merge(changedData);


        table.AcceptChanges();


    }

    private static void Adapter_RowUpdated(object sender, SqlRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        // If this is an insert, then skip this row.
        if (e.StatementType != StatementType.Insert) return;
        if (e.Status == UpdateStatus.ErrorsOccurred)
        {
            // here it will show an error that the retrieved Identity column is already exist on the dataTable. Because we still didn't update the second row
            throw e.Errors;
        }
        e.Status = UpdateStatus.SkipCurrentRow;
    }
```

now the issue that I fill my dataTable when stating the app so the datatable would have no rows only the schema.

and later another user using the same app insert a row on the database. but my dataTable would not know about this row.

after that I insert two rows on my dataTable and try to retrieve Identity column values. but it shows me this error.

Does anyone have an easy fast way to fix this issue. Like disabling constraints or something. I don't know.

Note: the way I retrieve the Identity value is explained here and I did as they explained. [how to retrieve Identity value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-identity-or-autonumber-values)

Comment: I tried to clear the constraints doing this changedData.Constraints.Clear(); and then later returning them and it worked. but is this the correct way doing this ? I don't know I need your advice

Answer (score 0):

1. Possible workaround can be that you use for e.g.  `SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Table` + 1  to get Last inserted ID before you are doing insert. And in INSERT you can do

   SET IDENTITY_INSERT yourTable ON
   INSERT INTO yourTable
   (IdentityColumn, col2)
   VALUES
   (Identity, col2value )
   SET IDENTITY_INSERT yourTable OFF
2. Try to set up AutoIncrementSeed and AutoIncrementStep property of your identy column in DataTable to -1.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.autoincrement?view=netframework-4.8) is documentation in which they are saying : "You can create a new row using the ItemArray property of the DataRow class and passing in an array of values. This is a potential problem for a column with its AutoIncrement set to true. " I know you are not using ItemArray but maybe you are dealing with something similar.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. the code that I provided it's not all my actual code. I just simulated what is actually happening with me. I can't select the max value because this will affect the performance. the issue appears when multi users are working on the same time. but if only one user is working everything goes fine. the problem I think is when the dataAdapter try to update the DataTable with the retrieved value. it shows this error because the second dataRow has the same retrieved identity value for the first row.

Comment: @Shebab if you set AutoIncrement=false; of IdentityColumn  It didnt helps ?